# A puzzle with 10 pieces - 2 days to complete

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

***All answers relate to something. What is it?***

> 1. An alien cent
> 2. Stretched-out
> 3. A volume of alcohol
> 4. Narcotics-induced state
> 5. A Spartan film + 1.
> 6. 6(2)
> 7. To debate
> 8. Leading the grid
> 9. Unit of asparagus
> 10. A Roman medical degree

*And as a bonus: how does the answer relate to the title?*

Hint 1:

> As some may already have realised: you don't have to complete the puzzle in 2 days, nor is anything special going to happen after waiting ;)

Hint 2:

> -The 10 answers will be in an order relevant for the final answer.
>  -It will be very difficult to find the answer with only a few answer and then trying to relate the other answers to it. Try to answer as many as possibly and evaluate the whole thing.

Comment: Are you sure [tag:cryptic-clues] applies? These don't seem like actual cryptic (crossword) clues which have a very specific structure.

Comment: @Alconja I was doubting about that one. The clue is not important is solving, so I will remove it

Comment: I found the answer, but given the title, I'll wait 2 days to post it. [rot13](https://rot13.com/)(Whfg xvqqvat: V unira'g ernyyl fbyirq vg.)

Comment: Hint added. No big one, but you should be able to figure it out anyway! Good luck

Comment: As I was reprimanded for putting a "non-answer", I'll ask in these comments: rot13(Qbrf 2 qnlf ersre gb gur yratgu bs n onggyr? Be fbzr bgure uvfgbevpny rirag? )

Comment: @JS1 rot13(Gur yratgu qbrf abg eryngr gb n uvfgbevpny rirag. Vg qbrf eryngr gb gur qhengvba bs fbzrguvat.)

Comment: @JS1 I've voted to undelete your answer, as it's definitely a partial answer (you've solved, probably correctly, some of the clues).

Comment: Hint 2 added. Keep trying, I'm sure you will find the answer!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This list of TEN clues relates to:

> Events in a **DECATHLON**

As follows:

*An alien cent*

> 'Cent' in French is **100** = *100 metres* (thanks to @hdsdv in comments)

*Stretched-out*

> **LONG** = *Long jump*

*A volume of alcohol*

> **SHOT** = *Shot put*

*Narcotics-induced state*

> **HIGH** = *High jump*

*A Spartan film + 1.*

> Adding together 'A Spartan film' (*300*) and the answer to clue 1. above (100) gives the answer **400** = *400 metres*

*6(2)*

> 6 in binary (base 2) is **110** = *110m hurdles*

*To debate*

> **DISCUSS** = *Discus throw*

*Leading the grid*

> **POLE** position = *Pole vault*

*Unit of asparagus*

> **SPEAR** = a synonym of *Javelin*

*A Roman medical degree*

> MD (Medical Degree) in Roman numerals is **1500** = *1500 metres*

The link with the title is that:

> A decathlon takes place over 2 consecutive days, with 5 events on each (and generally in the order of these clues).

Comment: rot13(prag vf Serapu sbe uhaqerq). Nice work!

Comment: Excellent work, this is the correct answer! Regarding question 1: **hdsdv** is right, that was what I was aiming at. It also relates to rot13(pragvzrgre pragvyvgre naq fb ba). For question 5; this is not exactly what I'm aiming for. The Spartan film is correct, but take a look at the markup of the question. Why would you add that number? Specify that and the tick is yours.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial with a stab at overall**

Based on the few I've got so far, I'm wondering are they all

> numbers. Possibly more specifically, common HTTP response codes.Maybe references to them, not all numeric

1. An alien cent
2. Stretched-out

   > Prone? Supine?
3. A volume of alcohol

   > cc? So, 200 = OK
4. Narcotics-induced state

   > High? 410=Gone?
5. A Spartan film + 1.

   > 300+1 = 301 = Moved Permanently
6. 6(2)

   > 12? VI VI?
7. To debate

   > Conflict (409)???
8. Leading the grid

   > Pole?
9. Unit of asparagus

   > Spear?
10. A Roman medical degree

    > MD = 1500. Which might be 500 with it's own Internal Server Error

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer

> I think all answers are file name extensions.

- **An alien cent**

> **fen**: the equivalent of a cent in China / Forsyth–Edwards Notation

- **Stretched-out**

> **big**: Electronic Arts Game Data File

- **A volume of alcohol**

> **abv**: alcohol by volume / Alcohol-Units-Calculator for Mac is using this extension

- **Narcotics-induced state**
- **A Spartan film + 1.**

> **301**: Brooktrout 301 Image

- **6(2)**
- **To debate**

> **tiff**: tagged image format file

- **Leading the grid**

> **1st**: usually README.1ST text file

- **Unit of asparagus**

> **rod**: RIB office Database File

- **A Roman medical degree**

Comment: I is nice to see how you found so many answers in that category. However, I'm going to stop you now. It's not what I'm looking for. rot13(Zbfg nafjref gb gur dhrfgvbaf ner abg jung V nz ybbxvat sbe. Cebonoyl orpnhfr zbfg ner cvpxrq nsgre gur pubvpr sbe svyr rkgrafvbaf. Fvapr gurer ner fb znal svyr rkgrafvbaf, V org lbh jbhyq or noyr gb svaq bar fbzrubj fhvgnoyr sbe rirel dhrfgvba.)

Answer (score 0):

**Partial**

Building up on @Steafar's answer about the clues refering to

> file extensions

- A Roman medical degree

> .dds (a raster image saved in the DirectDraw Surface (DDS) container format)

Comment: See the comment to @Sleafar 's answer

Answer (score -1):

**Partial answer**

1. An alien cent

> Foreign currency

2. Stretched-out

> wide (?)

3. A volume of alcohol
4. Narcotics-induced state
5. A Spartan film + 1

> 301

6. 6(2)

> 12 (?)

7. To debate
8. Leading the grid

> Square 1

9. Unit of asparagus
10. A Roman medical degree

Comment: (... so how does this contribute toward a solution? As this stands, it's *Not an Answer*, not even a partial one. Having fragmentary thoughts on aspects of a puzzle might be comment-worthy, but you probably want at least a germ of an idea that seems to lead forward before you should post as even a partial answer.)

Comment: @Deusovi Hi. I expected my smaller answers (if they turned out to be correct) can be used by others to build upon and find a solution. Thank you for the correction.